# How to write this self join based on three columns

Tags: mysql, join

Hello there I have a following table

```
------------------------------------------
| id | language | parentid | no_daughter |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |    0     |      2      |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |    0     |      2      |
------------------------------------------
| 2  |     1    |    1     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 2  |     2    |    1     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 3  |     1    |    1     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 3  |     2    |    1     |      0      |    
------------------------------------------
| 4  |     1    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 4  |     2    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     1    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2    |    2     |      1      |
-----------------------------------------
| 5  |     1    |    4     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2    |    4     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
```

**Scenario**

Every record has more than one rows in table with different `language` ids. `parentid` tells who is the parent of this record. `no_daughter` columns tells against each record that how many child one record has. Means in Ideal scenario If `no_daughter` has value `2` of `id = 1` , it means `1` should be `parentid` of 2 records in same table. **But If a record has more than one exitance with respect to language, it will be considered as one record**.

**My Problem**

I need to find out those records where `no_daughter` value is not correct. It means if `no_daughter` is 2, there must be two records whoes `parentid` has that id. In above case record with `id = 1` is valid. But record having `id = 2` is not valid because the `no_daughter = 1` but actual daughter of this record is 2. Same is the case with `id=4`

Can any body tell me how can I find these faulty records?

**So far help received**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
id 
FROM
tbl_info t 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    parentid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS childs 
  FROM
    tbl_info 
  GROUP BY parentid) AS parentchildrelation 
  ON t.id = parentchildrelation.parentid 
  AND t.no_daughters != parentchildrelation.childs
```

This query is returning those ids who have been used as `parentid` somewhere in table but having wrong `no_daughter` values. But not returning ids that has value in `no_daugter` columns but have not been used as `parentid` any where in table. For exampl `id = 5` has `no_daughter = 1` but it is not used as `parentid` in table. So it is also a faulty record. But above query is not capturing such records.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any instances in which an id can have a different parent for each language, say id 5 has parent with id 1 for language 1 and parent with id 4 for language 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your provided query is that you're doing an `INNER JOIN`. Because there are no rows with a parentid of 5, the subquery would return NULL on those rows and be excluded.

What you want is a `LEFT JOIN`, something like this ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4405f/19)):

```
SELECT t.*, parentchildrelation.parentid, childs
FROM tbl_info t
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    parentid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS childs 
  FROM
    tbl_info  
  GROUP BY parentid) AS parentchildrelation 
  ON t.id = parentchildrelation.parentid 
WHERE t.no_daughter != parentchildrelation.childs 
   OR (t.no_daughter > 0 AND parentchildrelation.parentid IS NULL)
GROUP BY t.id, t.parentid;
```

I included more columns, because where `id=5 and parentid=2` has two different values for no_daughter. You should be able to adjust those as needed.